# Console Application, App Freezes No Errors

Tags: c#, console

Okay at the moment I my self am new to programming and learning it slowly. At the moment I am taking programming classes to help better understand programming. I have ran in to a problem that has stumped me.

Now while I can do the assignment in a different way and manner as compared to what I provided. My question is, why is this happening? I get no errors, what so ever, the only thing that happens is after the input the Console Fezzes. I want to know what I did wrong.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    double[] Population = new double[6];
    string[] Years = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };
    double GrowthPercentage = 0.0;
    double MathPercentage = 0.0000;
    double ActualGrowth = 0.0;
    int WhileCounter = 0;

    //Ask user for Population of Roarkville
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Population of RoarkVille: ");
    //Read Population and store
    Population[0] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    //Ask user for Growth percentage
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Growth percentage ");
    //Read Growth Percentage
    GrowthPercentage = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    //Calculation of Growth Percentage: Growth Percentage/100 = Math Percentage 
    MathPercentage = GrowthPercentage / 100;
    //ActualGrowth = Population * Math Percentage 

    //Population2 = ActualGrowth + Population 

    while (WhileCounter < 5)
    {
       ActualGrowth = Population[WhileCounter] + MathPercentage;

       WhileCounter++;

       Population[WhileCounter] = ActualGrowth + Population[WhileCounter--];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Population.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Population of 201{0:d}", Years[i]);
        Console.WriteLine(Population[i]);
    }
    //Display 2012 Population 

    //Display 2013 Population 

    //Display 2014 Population 

    //Display 2015 Population 

    //Display 2016 Population 

    //Display 2017 Population

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's this line:  Population[WhileCounter] = ActualGrowth + Population[WhileCounter--];
You are decreasing WhileCounter, making it always 0

Comment: @ThomasOwers some guess.

Comment: What Thomas said. Just change it to Population[WhileCounter] = ActualGrowth + Population[WhileCounter- 1];

Comment: @ThomasOwers: Should have posted that comment as an answer.

Comment: @EdS. Oh well, was only 99% sure at the time!

Comment: Also Jake - you should read up on using the debugger. I am guessing you are using Visual Studio (express editions are free). When you start your program with F5, you can use Debug > Break All. This will break the execution of the program and you can step through the code line by line with F10. This link has more information about the ide - http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms165088.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ++ operator changes the actual value of the variable, so `WhileCounter++` increases the variable by 1

The -- operator does the same, which is not what you want to do in the line

```
Population[WhileCounter] = ActualGrowth + Population[WhileCounter--];
```

Instead, use `WhileCounter - 1` , like so

```
Population[WhileCounter] = ActualGrowth + Population[WhileCounter - 1];
```

Answer (score 3):

so what happen is that when you input on the growth percentage using this code:

```
    while (Counter < 5)
    {
    ActualGrowth = Population[Counter] + MathPercentage;

    Counter++;

    Population[Counter] = ActualGrowth + Population[Counter--];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Population.Length; i++)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Population of 201{0:d}", Years[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(Population[i]);
    }
```

the numbers that will you input will be infinite on the growth percentage:

this one can help you also

```
    while (Counter < 5)
    {
    ActualGrowth = Population[Counter] + MathPercentage;

    Counter++;

    Population[Counter] = ActualGrowth + Population[Counter-1];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Population.Length; i++)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Population of 201{0:d}", Years[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(Population[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WhileCounter++;

Population[WhileCounter] = ActualGrowth + Population[WhileCounter--];
```

The value of `WhileCounter` never changes as far as the loop is concerned.  In the loop body you increment `WhileCounter` and proceed to immediately decrement it, so the condition `WhileCounter < 5` is always true.

You may as well have written

```
int WhileCounter = 0;
while(WhileCounter < 5)  
{
    WhileCounter += 1;  // WhileCounter == 1
    WhileCounter -= 1;  // WhileCounter == 0
}

// aint never gunna happen
```

Comment: Well I changed the WhileCounter to be less then 5, was an attempt at a fix, orgigonally it was (WhileCounter < Population.Length);

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on the following operators and understand what they actually do:

[--](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc3z3k8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)